# provide SQL query to provide data in table1 which is not present in table2

Tags: sql-server-2008

i was asked the following question in an interview: 
provide SQL query to provide data in table1 which is not present in table2. 
Can anyone plese help me on this

Comment: Use NOT IN to make it working. Also provide both table schemas to have more to-the-point answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested select queries

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE blah_id NOT IN (SELECT blah_id FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The point here is not an one approach, several approaches and the best tuned one.

If you explain NOT IN or EXCEPT, the next question could be performance. The interviewer may additinally ask if the tables are huge what could be the approach, The one below could be  one of the tuned answer.

**Use Tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab2 ON Common ID's WHERE Tab2.Column IS NULL**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Location,Hub,Agency FROM blu.MediaTable 

EXCEPT 

SELECT LocationRollup,Hub,Deccription FROM nop.TempMedia
```